# Solving a PDE with a spatially piecewise-constant material parameter

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate, finite-element-method

I would like to solve equation for the 2D distribution of an electrical potential in the conductive medium:

$$\nabla\cdot(\sigma\nabla f) = 0$$

where $f=f(x,y)$ is the electric potential (in 2D) and sigma is the conductivity. The domain where the equation is solved is complex. For instance, like this:

```
 Manipulate[
 t1 = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {x, y}, {1, 0}}];
 t2 = Triangle[{{0, 1}, {x, y}, {1, 1}}];
 t3 = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {x, y}, {0, 1}}];
 t4 = Triangle[{{1, 0}, {x, y}, {1, 1}}];
 Graphics[{Blue, t1, Red, t2, Green, t3, Yellow, t4}, 
  ImageSize -> 300],
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Looking like the following:

[image]

The point is that each of the triangles should have its own value of the conductivity. It is constant within a triangle and changes by transition from one triangle to another. Say, for the sake of the trial, $\sigma=1, 2, 3$ and $4$. I would like to be able to manipulate the structure of the domain (as it is in the image shown above) and dynamically solve the equation depending upon the values $(x,y)$ fixed by the slider. 
The boundary conditions might be:

```
{ DirichletCondition[{f[x, y] == 0.}, y == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[{f[x, y] == 1.}, y == 1]}
```

and the no-flux conditions on two other sides of the square:

```
NeumannValue[0, x == 0 || x == 1]
```

Any idea of how to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach. In essence what you are looking for is a way to detach the geometry from the equations. You can do that with `ElementMarker`. Let me show how such an approach might look like. We generate a boundary mesh of the region. Note the second argument to the `LineElement` these are integer markes. Each outer edge gets an arbitrary marker; the inner edges are not relevant and we set them to 0. We also compute the center of mass (coms) for each triangle, we'll need those just now.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Manipulate[
 coords = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {x, y}};
 bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
       0}]}];
 coms = Total[coords[[#]]]/3 & /@ {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 
     5}, {4, 1, 5}};
 Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[coms]}],
  bmesh["Wireframe"]]
 , {x, 0.1, 0.9}, {y, 0.1, 0.9}]
```

[image]

Next, we generate the full mesh. The center of masses mark each region. In each of these sub-regions a different to the above edge marker is attributed. During the mesh generation process each triangle that is created gets attributed a marker depending in which sub-region it resides.

```
rm = Thread[List[coms, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]
(* {{{0.428`, 0.136`}, 1}, {{0.7613333333333332`, 0.46933333333333327`}, 
  2}, {{0.428`, 0.8026666666666666`}, 
  3}, {{0.09466666666666668`, 0.46933333333333327`}, 4}} *)
```

Generate the mesh from the boundary:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> rm];
```

Visualize the markers of the mesh elements:

```
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Blue], FaceForm[Yellow], 
    FaceForm[Red], FaceForm[Green]}]]
```

[image]

Investigate the boundary markers:

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Purple]]
```

[image]

One can go further and specify a refinement for each sub-region:

```
rm = Thread[
   List[coms, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 0.1*{0.01, 0.02, 0.005, 0.001}]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> rm];
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Blue], FaceForm[Yellow], 
    FaceForm[Red], FaceForm[Green]}]]
```

[image]

Now, for the actual PDE solving. Sigma is now a function of `ElementMarker` and can have different sigma values in the respective sub-regions.

```
sigma = Which[ElementMarker == 1, {{3, 0}, {0, 3}}, 
   ElementMarker == 2, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 
   ElementMarker == 3, {{10, 0}, {0, 10}}, 
   ElementMarker == 4, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
```

With this the call to `NDSolve` is decoupled from geometry. This call to `NDSolve` will work for any geometry that provides the needed markers. The `DirichletConditions` use the `LineElement` markers and the PDE coefficients use the mesh element markers. So even though we have an edge marker 1 and a mesh element marker 1, these are distinct because they operate on different levels.

```
if = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Div][
      sigma.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, ElementMarker == 3]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

Visualize the result:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[if, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"],
 bmesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

More information about markers can be found in the documentation for [ToBoundaryMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html) and [ToElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) in the options section under `RegionMarker` and in the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Comment: Great, thank you.  It looks like a solution for any division of the domain into parts.